# Which image should replace the question mark?

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

The answer to this puzzle is an image.

[image]

Could you figure it out?

---

### Hints:

Hint 1:

> [image]

Hint 2:

> [image]

Hint 3:

> ≈
>  [image]

Hint 4:

> There is land below the images.

Answer (score 4):

I'm recognizing

> military letters (X-Ray, Charlie, Tango, Oscar, Hotel) and maybe a rotation pattern: X (1 time), C (8 times), T (2 times), O (2 times), H (4 times).

My guess so far is that it has to be

> another phonetic letter.
>
>  If the letters correspond to numbers, tallying them up, dividing by 26 and taking the remainder (20), gets another Tango. I have the feeling that's not the solution but I wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: rot13(Lbh fgnegrq va gur evtug qverpgvba, ohg gur ebgngvba unf abguvat gb qb jvgu gung, nygubhtu vg vf vzcbegnag sbe fbyivat vg. Pna lbh guvax bs ubj pna gurfr yrggref or ercerfragrq va nabgure jnl?)

Comment: I thought it might have also been Foxtrot they are dancing :-)

Comment: rot13(Gur qbgf va gur uvag pbashfr zr, V'yy or vagrerfgrq gb frr jung gur nafjre vf)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite have it, but I suspect the image is:

> related to a map of India, something like this where the dots line up with specific cities.  The question mark would be an image representing a phonetic letter that indicates another city that matches the pattern of letters/pictures/locations.  I just can't quite make it work out. [image]

Piggybacking on Lucas' idea

> The pictures appear to be phonetic letters.

Hint 1:

> Those dots appear to be city marks from Google Maps (or similar)

Hint 2:

> is the inside of an eye . . . or "I" which is India

Hint 3:

> Appears to be approximately "~" a map of India rotated on its side.

Hint 4:

> Land underneath also implies that it's a map or dealing somehow with geography.

What I'm missing:

> I can't quite get the scale to work out or the angle right to make the letters line up with cities that start with or use those letters.  I'm also not sure how the rotation or duplication of the images tie in.  Two Oscars might be a city with two o's in the name, but I don't see anything with eight c's.  The rotation might lead to the angle of rotation of the map.

Comment: Mmmmm, almost done it! Hint 1 was really on the point, but your answer on the Hint 2 misguided you to the final solution. rot13(Gung vf abg na rlr). But you are right on rot13(Gur dhrfgvba znex jbhyq or na vzntr ercerfragvat n cubargvp yrggre gung vaqvpngrf nabgure pvgl gung zngpurf gur cnggrea bs yrggref/cvpgherf/ybpngvbaf).

Comment: Ha!  A reverse image search on google shows me that Hint 2 is actually rot13(Rhebcn). I feel silly.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the Charlie red dot and the lower Tango red dot over

> London and Paris

And adjust the projection of the map, the question mark red dot ends up over

> Kyiv, Ukraine

Comment: Nice find! But what are the other dots over, and how do these places fit with the theme and the Charlie/Tango/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on [brian](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/79415/brian)'s [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115683/50054), which gave me the following image:

> [image]

, I'm wondering if replacing the images by the letters they represent leads to...

> a crude representation of a monument/landmark/tourist attraction at that location. For example, "C"s in a circle could represent the London Eye, an upside-down "T" could represent the Eiffel Tower, the "X" could represent the Orthodox cross of the [Russalka Memorial](https://www.adequatetravel.com/blog/famous-monuments-in-estonia/).

Finding an answer:

> From this logic, we need some monument in eastern Ukraine that bears some resemblance to a sideways English letter. Looking around I found the Round Court. It is located here (which is good enough for me!):
>  [image]

> As shown from the image below, the court looks like an "O" when viewed from the west, so looking at it from the south (i.e., with north at the top of the image, like our map is), it would look like a sideways "O"
>  [image]

Therefore, I think the image we're looking for is

> [image]

Comment: I think the image in the first block is good and coud be adjusted rot13(sbe cebwrpgvba fb gung gur qbgf raq hc ba pncvgnyf), but I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion. Wouldn't rot13(gur Rvssry Gbjre or na hcevtug Nysn vafgrnq bs na vairegrq Gnatb? Naq jung'f jvgu gur qvssrerag fvmrf naq gur flzobyf ng Nzfgreqnz, Jnefnj, Zbanpb, Znqevq naq Oengvfynin/Ivraan)?

Comment: @MOehm Honestly? No idea (I thought about your alternative as well) - I was just throwing spaghetti at the wall to see if anything sticks since I couldn't find any other connection ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, I think the map has stuck, so good on your for doing that. `:)`